# Cannot get the full json with request json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase

When I am actually entering the XXXX YYYY, then I am getting the players json code in my html page (around 150 values).
But when I am trying to use a function on the players list it somewhy does not contain all the 150 values and the try throws me into the catch error part, where I can see that players json has only 100 players inside there.

Any idea what could be the problem?

```
if(yourID === "XXXX" && targetID === "YYYY"){
    return players;
}
try{
    if(isUserAlive(yourID)){
        if(targetID === ""){
            return userTargetInfo(yourID);
        }
        var checkForMatch = getUserTarget(yourID);
        if(checkForMatch === targetID){
            killTarget(targetID);
            getUser(yourID).targetID = getTargetTarget(targetID);
            addScore(yourID);
            return userTargetInfo(yourID);
            //return getTargetTargetStats(targetID);
        }else{
            return "INVALID";
        }
    }else{
        return "DEAD"
    }
}catch(err){
    console.log("Error",console.log(players))
    return "INVALID"    
}
```

Edit: Since I had no time, I created 2 websites and divided the database into 2 different databases, so it would work under 100 people on each. Did not have time to fix the error at this point. So I won't be choosing the solution to that since I won't be trying that any time soon. 
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've provided here, but I'm guessing whatever API you're requesting from is using pagination on it's players data, i.e., they only return a certain number of results with each request. Do you have api documentation that you can refer to?

Comment: If you hit the same url from postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) do you get all the values? It could be a limit on the server side?

Comment: The Firebase Database doesn't truncate the number of children returned unless you specify a `limitToFirst` or `limitToLast` parameter. It's impossible to say what's going on without seeing a [minimal, complete code sample that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One way to create such an MCVE is to reproduce the problem in a jsbin and then share the code and the link from there.

Comment: With postman I am actually getting all the content. And I cannot really give the json link too, because it contains info that I cannot share publicly

Comment: Are you sure that with Postman you are making the exact same request? I.e. a GET request to the same exact URL and nothing else?

Comment: yes. I am sure. I actually think I figured out where is the error coming from, but I have no idea why. 
Editing first post to show where is the error coming from

Answer (score 0):

Check the link api that you are using , it might have pagination integrated with it . in that case i will return certain number of object 1st and then you can re-request to get next batch .  Most likely they might have a option to change the no of object returned (sometimes with max value)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `body` is returned as a string. Try changing it to an object so you can work with it easier.

Change:

```
 players = body;
```

to:

```
 players = JSON.parse(body);
```

I'm not sure the rest of your code, but you may want to add `var` on your `players` variable declaration because this looks like the first time you are setting it.

> Research: namespace collisions

If you are still having issues, edit your question to include the response you are getting from `console.log(JSON.parse(body));`. You will be able to get more helpful answers. Personally, I am curious to see the keys such as:

```
 { query:
    { count: 1,
      created: '2017-04-23T22:03:31Z',
      lang: 'en-US',
      results: { channel: [Object] } } }
```

If it's paginated, you should see some kind of `cursor` key in there, or `prev` and `next` along with some kind of `totalCount`.

Hope this helps.